# Фигурные скобки в Java. Что происходит когда я опускаю скобки?

Tags: java

Есть один вопрос касаемо Java. 
Что происходит, когда я опускаю скобки как в примере ниже:

Без скобок:

```
for(...)
   someAction() ;
```

идентичный код со скобками:

```
for(...)
{
   someAction() ;
}
```

Использование или неиспользование скобок в этом примере как-то влияет на время компиляции или производительность ?

Comment: Этот сайт предназначен для вопросов на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Извините, не туда написал :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница в том, что без скобок будет выполняться только одна строка, следующая после цикла/условия/пр. В случае со скобками будет выполнено все внутри { }.  Если Вы на 99.9% уверены, что конструкция будет неизменна - можете писать без скобок. Чтобы не было впоследствии ситуации, что добавите еще 1 строчку, скобки забудете, а затем программа не так отработает.

Answer (score 4):

Скобки в принципе никак не влияют на производительность. Если говорить о компиляции, то что бы скобки начали влиять, вам их нужно будет поставить миллиард другой. Что касается кода, то для компилятора он идентичный.

Comment: Т.е. компилятор видит данный код идентично? Интересуют именно внутренние механизмы, сокрытые за этой частью кода

Comment: нет никаких скрытых механизмов. Просто после for (и после других подобных - if, else, while..) может быть только одно выражение. И если нужно написать несколько выражений, то нужно как то компилятору это объяснить. Для этого и нужны скобки. В питоне для этого используют отступы.

Comment: @IvanStin нету там никаких "внутренних" механизмов. Это просто синтаксис. И никакого синтаксического сахара там нет.